# Laravel Pagination shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." page

Tags: laravel

I have website which shows data with pagination in front page. it is working fine but when we click on page 5 it shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." but working fine on 4th page and 6th page 
Here is website scroll down and click on 5th page 
https://visionarywritings.com

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::where('admin','0')->where('active','1')->paginate(12);
    return view('frontend/index',compact('users',$users));
}
```

**Index blade**

```
{{$users->links()}}
```

**In Laravel.log it shows**

```
[2018-08-01 14:33:31] production.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/visionar/visionarywritings/resources/views/frontend/index.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/visionar/visionarywritings/resources/views/frontend/index.blade.php) at /home/visionar/visionarywritings/storage/framework/views/7cb57079700bd8e47f0208d23b62204f723ddd9b.php:44, ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at /home/visionar/visionarywritings/storage/framework/views/7cb57079700bd8e47f0208d23b62204f723ddd9b.php:44)
[stacktrace]
```

Comment: Check your logs; `storage/logs/laravel.log`, or `storage/logs/laravel-{year}-{month}-{day}.log` (if using `daily`). *"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."* is a placeholder to prevent showing errors when they're not supposed to be shown, but we can't debug anything without the actual error message.

Comment: I updated the question and added the error from laravel.log

Comment: Getting closer. Unfortunately, `Trying to get property of non-object` can mean anything is not an object. The view file `7cb57079700bd8e47f0208d23b62204f723ddd9b.php` is a cached version of `index.blade.php`; what code does `index.blade.php` at line 44 contain? (might be a few lines off; cached files have different line numbers than non-cached ones)

Comment: Try dump $users directly in view.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `User` data is not complete in whole table.

In 12 elements (5 page) maybe there is null or something else?

Check if every row has proper data.